# Two way browser link doesn't work on VS 2015 and webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and my project is an asp.net webforms. I have installed web essentials and I see the Browser Link icon in the menu bar and I have enabled all options. When I update the css style after "inspect element" and hit Ctrl + Alt + Enter it doesn't update the visual studio css code. It is an inline css style on an aspx page.

Thanks